# Call localhost service through Javascript sockets?

Tags: javascript, java, sockets, security, client-side

I am developing an app in AngularJS that needs to call a client side running service
on port 3000. The service is just a Java program that listen on that port and on determined params
call a printer or another peripheral machine connected to the computer.
I am not looking to call a web service or something similar.

Technically is that posible? If yes, then this will be the perfect replacement for the traditional
Java applets on client side. There is it the point where I want to go… If not, why?

Comment: what's the protocol on port 3000? you better use something common like HTTP or WebSocket.

Comment: The protocol is SOCKETS and I don't know if it works calling something like this: htt..://localhost:3000. Do you?

Comment: no... you need to run a web server on the client side. maybe use an embedded http server.